# How to test emails that are set to deliver later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I can't figure out how to get the syntax to work for asserting that an email has been enqueued properly. Specifically, **how do you pass in the arguments to the mailer when the argument is an object?**

For example, if you want to pass in a contact object to the example from the documentation:

```
  assert_enqueued_email_with ContactMailer, :welcome, @contact do
    ContactMailer.welcome(@contact).deliver_later
  end

  assert_enqueued_email_with ContactMailer, :welcome, args: @contact do
    ContactMailer.welcome.deliver_later
  end

  assert_enqueued_email_with ContactMailer, :welcome, [@contact] do
    ContactMailer.welcome.deliver_later
  end
```

None of these appear to work. If you look at the actual enqueued job, the object looks like this:

```
{:job=>ActionMailer::DeliveryJob, :args=>["ContactMailer", "welcome", "deliver_now", {"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://app_name/Contact/1015983224"}], :queue=>"mailers"}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is probably too late to help you, but I ran across the same issue recently, so hopefully this workaround will help the next person. Under the hood, [assert_enqueued_email_with](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/test_helper.rb#L126) just uses [assert_enqueued_with](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activejob/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb#L382), and we can use it directly to create a test that will find the enqueued email like so.

```
assert_enqueued_with(job: ContactMailer.delivery_job, args: ['ContactMailer', 'welcome', 'deliver_now', @contact], queue: 'mailers')
```

The only difference between this test, and what assert_enqueued_email_with generates is @contact isn't wrapped in an extra array.

Edit: I wanted to come back in to mention that I only encountered this error during the middle of an update from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.0. Once I got further into the update this went away and assert_enqueued_with worked as expected, while the previous workaround using assert_enqueued_with no longer matched. Specifically it was after setting delivery_job to the new default.

```
Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_job = "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass an array of arguments:

```rb
assert_enqueued_email_with ContactMailer, :welcome, args: [@contact] do
  ContactMailer.welcome(@contact).deliver_later
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so my solution was to access the array of enqueued jobs directly and do a comparison manually.

```
assert_equal ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs[0][:args][0], "UserMailer"
assert_equal ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs[1][:args][0], "MarketingMailer"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try specifying wait time

```
Notifier.welcome(User.first).deliver_later(wait: 1.hour)
```

More options for deliver_later:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The problem is the assert_enqueued_email_with method doesn't appear to work with an object as an argument.